# TabHost obtaining previous tab after a tab change

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have a TabHost and have set an onTabChangeListener. In onTabChange() is it possible to determine the previous tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not, you'll have to store that information yourself. Just keep a record of previous tab in your class that listens for onTabChange()